# Solr: how to add a new field to all docs

Tags: solr, solr4

I need to add a new field to each document in a Solr index.

This new field does not need to be searchable. It is just needed to be stored in Solr and returned in the search results.

The value of the new field can be calculated based on the id field (and other info which is not present in the solr index.)

What is the fastest, most simple way to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [Solr Schema API](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Schema+API):

```
curl http://localhost:8983/solr/yourcollection/schema -X POST -H 'Content-type:application/json' --data-binary '{
    "add-field" : {
    "name":"myfield",
    "type":"string",
    "stored":true
    }
}'
```

Filling the value of this field for the existing documents can be done AFAIK only with a reindex operation.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not solve my problem. The value of the new field is not available at the time of indexing. It comes from an other source, other then the indexed data.

Comment: Probably in this case you'll only need to update your field once you have its value available. You can do this through [Solr Atomic Updates](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Updating+Parts+of+Documents#UpdatingPartsofDocuments-AtomicUpdates) . One example: `curl http://localhost:8983/solr/yourcollection/update?commitWithin=3000 -d '[{"id":"your_doc_id", "myfield": {"set", "field value"}}]'`